# How to make relationship without using modelname_id in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use one to many relationship for post and category.And for the database columns,If i use like this

```html
  Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

in Post model

```
    public function Category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

in category model

```
 public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

Its working if i use above method like **$table->integer('category_id')**.But i want to use **custom name** like
 **$table->integer('cat_id')** without using category_id like

```html
  Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
             $table->integer('cat_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

.I am using laravel 5.4 and please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out Laravel's site on [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) under **One To Many**  relationships, you'll see:

> Like the hasOne method, you may also override the foreign and local keys by passing additional arguments to the hasMany method:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key');

return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

This is also the case for `$this->belongsTo` which is just an inverse One To Many relationship. So in your case:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'cat_id');
```

Comment: but if i use like above u mentioned and in my view i use like  {{$post->category->name}} it just showing like " Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: Are you using eager loading when fetching your posts? Something like `Post::with('Category')`?

Comment: $posts = Post::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10);
       return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));    like this?

Comment: You should really read Laravel's site on Eager Loading https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading - It's not enough to define the relationships. You have to use `with()` to fetch the relationships when you fetch the data

Comment: Ahh, i see  
$posts = Post::with('Category')->paginate(10); , still not okie sir, any idea bro? , thank you so much for your patient anyway, i need to figure this issue seriously.

Comment: I think you've mixed up your relationships. I figure that your posts only have a single category - so your Post model should use a hasOne relationship with category. And category then belongsTo Post

Comment: Thank you so much daniel, i fixed it now. yay.

Comment: Btw Daniel, have you happen "Trying to get property of non-object " after go to next page (pagination) like $posts = Post::with('Category')->paginate(10);